# Cannot reach Spring boot application in Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a Eureka Discovery Service build with Spring Boot 3.
I created Dockerfile file with following content:

```docker
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/openjdk/jdk:17-ubuntu

RUN addgroup --system spring
RUN adduser --system spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8880:8880
```

When I do `docker ps` I could see the app:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
e80974c83e6c   7bb35c99e929   "java -jar /app.jar"   51 seconds ago   Up 50 seconds   8880/tcp   magical_lichterman
```

Docker inspect returns me following IP address of container

```
docker inspect   -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' e80974c83e6c
172.17.0.2
```

But when I try to reach 172.17.0.2:8880 then I got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Any Ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Why not just `localhost`? Assuming you are running locally. Also have you checked if your application is actually started, the fact your container started doesn't mean the application did.

Comment: you need to know network in docker. I suggest you should  watch  [this tutotiral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKFMS5C4CG0) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where is the request comes from.

- If you try from a different container, make sure they are on the same network.

```bash
docker network create my-network
docker run --name spring-app -d --network my-network <your_image> # your spring container
docker run -d --network my-network <your_other_image> # should make a request to "http://spring-app:8080"
```

- If you try to access from the host you should open the container port

```bash
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 <your_image>
```

Then try running `curl http://localhost:8080`.